# How to add custom attribute (checkbox)?

Tags: magento

I can add a checkbox by editing the following file manually:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
```

but how can I add an custom attribute (checkbox) without editing this file via magento module and how to save the value to database?

I already know how to create a module but I just dont get, how to create custom attribute with magento modules.

I really need some advice, where to begin or how.

Comment: You mean you need to create custom order attribute?

Comment: Yes I guess, I need to add a new attribute to sales_flat_order db and change it via checkbox

Comment: ok let me provide you steps in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create folder: Orderattribute
Path: `app/code/local/Custom/`

Create file config.xml.
Path: `app/code/local/Custom/Orderattribute/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Orderattribute>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Custom_Orderattribute>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote>
                <package_attr>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </package_attr>
            </sales_convert_quote>
            <sales_convert_order>
                <package_attr>
                    <to_quote>*</to_quote>
                </package_attr>
            </sales_convert_order>
        </fieldsets>
        <resources>
            <orderattribute_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Custom_Orderattribute</module>
                    <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </orderattribute_setup>
        </resources>
        <resources>
            <orderattribute_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Custom_Orderattribute</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </orderattribute_setup>
        </resources>
        <helpers>
            <orderattribute>
                <class>Custom_Orderattribute_Helper</class>
            </orderattribute>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Create folder:
Path: `app/code/local/Custom/Orderattribute/Helper`

Create Helper.php file:
Path: `app/code/local/Custom/Orderattribute/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php

class Custom_Orderattribute_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

}
```

Create folder:
Path:

```
app/code/local/Custom/Orderattribute/sql
```

Create Folder
Path: `app/code/local/Custom/Orderattribute/orderattribute_setup`

Create file mysql4-install-0.1.0.php
Path: `app/code/local/Custom/Orderattribute/orderattribute_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php`

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute("order", "package_attr", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute("quote", "package_attr", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->endSetup();
```

Modify this file:

```
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\info.phtml

<?php if($_order->getPackageAttr()): ?>
<?php $status='checked'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<tr>
    <td class="label"><label><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Other Options') ?></label></td>
    <td class="value"><strong> <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="My option" <?php echo $status; ?>></strong></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you, not tested yet. Just a question: Do I need to add a attribute to quote too? because I only want to add to sales_flat_order?

Comment: ok than you can remove this code $installer->addAttribute("quote", "package_attr", array("type"=>"varchar"));